# include_blank not working for select_year rails form input Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some odd reason, the year is still showing as the default value for the select_year input that rails offers. I cannot get include_blank: "Select Year" to populate the form input. How can I force the select_year/select_month input to show the include_blank text instead of the current year/current day value? fyi: prompt also doesn't work for the input

**_calendar_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag calendar_path(@calendar), method: :get do %>
<%= select_year(Date.today, {:prompt => "Select Year", :start_year => DateTime.now.year, :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 8, prefix: 'select'}, {:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year', class: 'ui dropdown', include_blank: 'Select Year'}) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because [your first argument is the value it should set](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_year), as in `Date.today`
You can set that to `nil` to get it to work. You can also just skip the `include_blank` since you also have `prompt`

```
<%= select_year nil, {prompt: "Select Year", start_year: DateTime.now.year, end_year: 8.years.ago.year, prefix: 'select'}, {field_name: 'year', id: 'start-year', class: 'ui dropdown', include_blank: 'Select Year'} %>
```

Usually you will set this in a controller variable

```
def new 
  @date = nil
end

def create
  @date = some_params[:year] # depending on use-case obviously
  # if you need to re-render the form the value is retained
end    

= select_year @date ......
```

Comment: I didn't realize that I could set it to nil, given the documentation that only shows the value as the first argument. Thank you.